# Жаргонизм "обдолбанный"

Tags: жаргон, нн

Подскажите, будьте добры, правильно ли писать в кратком прилагательном "обдолбанна" две "н"? И действительно ли это прилагательное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ориентироваться на издательскую практику, то близкое по смыслу (частный случай "обдолбанности") и распространенное в современной беллетристике выражение "**была обкурена**" (полная форма: "обкуренная") устойчиво пишется с *одним* "н". Это говорит о том, что слово трактуется как краткое *причастие*, а не прилагательное. Видимое основание для этого - подразумеваемое недавнее *действие* (приведение в состояние "обдолбанности"), скрытое умозаключение о нём по внешним признакам "обдолбанной": ба, да она нанюхалась кокаина - она явно **обдолбана**! Поэтому вариант с *двумя* "н" представляется *неверным*.